# Use PowerShell to conditionally restart a service on remote computers

Tags: powershell

Because this is in PROD makes it hard to test without having a sandbox. I know how to get my list and filter it down. Computers are stored in GW.txt

GWs.txt

```
cgwaib209
cgwaib208
cgwmib208
cgwaob207
cgwaob206
cgwaob205
cgwaib201
cgwmib201
cgwaob202
cgwaob203
```

`Get-Content .\GWs.txt | ForEach-Object { if ($_ -match $regex){Get-Service -ComputerName $_ | where {($_.Name -like "Cell Gateway Service*")-and ($_.Status -eq "Running")}}}`

I know how to restart local services

```
Get-Service -Name "Gaming*" | Restart-Service -PassThru
```

But will a pipe work for the remote ones or do I need a nested loop?

Comment: your code is not complete & will not run properly since you failed to define `$regex`. please, add that info to your Question. also, it is helpful to be acle to see a sample of the `GWs.txt` file. [*grin*]

Comment: oops! i forgot to mention that the info need to be in your Question - it's nearly unreadable elsewhere.

Comment: Moved from comment to updated question

Comment: thanks! ... now, where is the `$Regex` value? [*grin*]

Comment: I started working on this the other week. Can't recall which on-line source I got it from but it was written out like that. Figured it meant to look for any value that wasn't null incase there were empty lines

Comment: `Get-Service "Cell Gateway Service*" -ComputerName (cat .\GWs.txt) | ? {$_.Status -eq "Running"} | Restart-Service -PassThru` could already work, if the user that executes this command has sufficient permissions on the remote computers

Comment: @AlexR - one way to test for "not empty" is `| Where-Object {$_}`. that will only pass on items that are not blank. another is to replace that `$_` with `-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the computer names from the file to an array and then use [Invoke-Command](https://ss64.com/ps/invoke-command.html) and pass the array to the `-ComputerName` parameter and run the `Get-Service` conditional logic within a `-ScriptBlock` using the `-AsJob` parameter to pass the processing of the commands off to each machine iterated.

```
$cred = Get-Credential "domain\administrator" 
$Machines = Get-Content .\GWs.txt;

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Machines -ScriptBlock { Process {
    Get-Service | ? {$_.Name -like "Cell Gateway Service*" -and $_.Status -eq "Running"} | Restart-Service -Force -Passthru
    }
} -AsJob -Credential $cred
```

Using `Invoke-Command` with the `-AsJob` parameter executes the command on the remote system as a background job, and then moves on doing the same for each subsequent server in the list.

---

### Supporting Resources

- [Enable-PSRemoting](https://ss64.com/ps/enable-psremoting.html)
- [Invoke-Command](https://ss64.com/ps/invoke-command.html)

> `-ScriptBlock scriptblock`
>
> The commands to run.
>
> Enclose the commands in curly braces `{ }` to
> create a script block. This parameter is required.
>
> By default, any
> variables in the command are evaluated on the remote computer. To
> include local variables in the command, use `-ArgumentList` or in
> PowerShell 3.0+ *use the prefix **`$using:`** before the local variable* to be
> passed e.g.  `{ echo $using:mylocalVar }`

Comment: Appreciate this, Thank you. I'll have to get permission to run it and test. Maybe with Stop-Service first. 

Manually connecting to the 12 machines is such a headache.

Comment: @AlexR Wanted to circle back to this and get an update from you on it. What's the status on the latest you have with the method I provided?

Comment: Apologies. I've since moved on ( from the company )  and was never able to test.

Comment: @AlexR Since you're not able to test and I'm the only one that answered, consider accepting it since you cannot confirm since you've moved on for the name of completeness at least. I tried to help and feel confident based on my experience this variation would work.